# How to get the first and the last date in a file

Tags: python

I have a text-file with several dates. The dates a cronical sorted at the beginning of every line (after header) like:

```
2013-10-20, text
2013-10-21, text
2013-10-22, text
2013-10-23, text
```

I would like to get "2013-10-20" and "2013-10-23".

I have a bunch of files with different dates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to get first and last lines in file Is to read all the file to a `list` and get the first and last item.

```
with open('youFile.txt','r') as fp:
    linesList = fp.readlines()
    # get the first
    first = linesList[0]
    # get the last
    last = linesList[-1]
```

Comment: why `rb` mode? `beginning of every line (after header)` - need to skip header.

Comment: @sheh `rb` (binary format) it's a mistake (copied from my code), i've fixed that.

Comment: As long as the data isn't too large.

Answer (score 1):

you can get first and last lines from following code.

```
 with open(yourfile, "r") as f:
        first = f.readline()     
        f.seek(-2, 2)            
        while f.read(1) != "\n": 
            f.seek(-2, 1)        
        last = f.readline()
```

if you want to get the date only, either you can use a regular expression or simply as following.

```
first = first.split(',')[0]
last = last.split(',')[0]
```

Comment: Very nice!  I thought "ideally we should seek to the end of the file, but that seems kind of hard."  You just showed that it really isn't that hard!

Comment: @steveha : Thanks, always trying on finding the simplest way. :)

Answer (score 0):

not so simple alternative

```
    f = open('filepath','r')
    //f.seek(0)
    import string
    a = string.split(f.read(),'\n')
    firstdate=string.split(a[0],',')[0]
    lastdate=string.split(a[len(a)-1],',')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice simple way to do it.

```
import sys

def extract_date(line):
    date, _, _ = line.partition(',')
    return date.strip()


_, fname = sys.argv

with open(fname, "rt") as f:
    line = next(f)
    first_date = extract_date(line)
    for line in f:
        pass
    last_date = extract_date(line)


print("first: {}  last: {}".format(first_date, last_date))
```

You can use this same technique with any iterator... grab the first value with `next()` then keep taking values from the iterator until it is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file and use a `csv.reader`, take the first line or default to an empty list and then use a deque to consume the rest of the file keeping one row at a time, and either take that row or the first row again:

```
from collections import deque
import csv

with open('input') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    first = next(csvin, [])
    last = next(iter(deque(csvin, 1)), first)

print first[0], last[0] # assuming date is field column
```

Alternatively, use a `mmap`'d file:

```
import mmap

with open('input') as fin:
    mf = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    first = mf.readline()
    last = mf[mf.rfind('\n'):]
```